# angular-ui: where is the page $scope inside a <script> element? For a google chart

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I'm trying to add a chart to code created by others.
I understand a bit of angular, only...

I'm using angular-ui, so I don't have access to the HEAD tag where the simple Google instructions say to put the SCRIPT tags.  I tried putting it later in the html, with other SCRIPT tags, but it kept saying "google" was undefined.

Finally, it seems to work if I put it inside the onload function:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    drawCharts = function() {
        var is = issue;
        ... create the chart using data inside $scope.issue
    }

    // google.charts.load( -- DOESN'T WORK HERE, google is undefined

    $(window).load(function () {
        // finally, in here, 'google' is defined
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart', 'bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
    }
```

PROBLEM: drawCharts() needs to access the $scope, but here there's no access to $scope, so my angular data isn't accessible and drawCharts() fails.

So somewhere I need to connect
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback()  and  $scope
How?

---

I found one question where the person had a:

```
$rootScope
    .$on('$viewcontentLoaded', function(...)
```

But he has it in main.js, and I don't have a main.js.

I tried putting it in my controller for the page, but it doesn't define $rootScope.  I tried adding $rootScope to the parameters passed to the first line of my controller:

```
people.controller("voterIssueCtrl", function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $cookieStore, $window, ClIENT
```

And that took care of the undefined $rootScope, but the $viewContentLoaded function was never called (it just contained a console.log() message...)

Perhaps my app.js is his main.js.
But it references the controller by name, so it probably loads it, so it probably can't reference something the controller defines.

Help?

===============
I pulled a google chart directive from the web
added the  tag in index.html to pull it in
and added the directive to my module definition.
(Of course I forgot the 2nd one and the code didn't complain...)
Nothing. But no complaint that Google wasn't known...
Putting in sample data helps.
In the grand style of js and angular, it doesn't complain if the data isn't exactly in the form it needs...
If only Angular2 + Typescript had been invented sooner...

Comment: You can set something like window.myScope = $scope inside the controller but the real answer if that you should probably write a directive that wraps the google code.

Comment: Thanks much.  That's what I feared.

How?  I'm searching for "google chart angular" and see some examples, but they're not clear...  I need a directive to which I pass a function, I think. And then define the function as $scope.name in my controller?
Can I just put the directive in a file next to my controller file?

Comment: You probably want a directive you pass the data to, rather than a function, and then in the controller you'll resolve the data.  And yes, you can definitely declare a directive in the same file, although it might be easier to read if you kept it to one controller/directive per file.

Comment: I looked for a suitable directive, but none seems clear...  Thanks anyway.  Maybe I'll look for a consultant...

Comment: You could ask more specifically about what you're stuck with, I guess.